# Auto scrolldown after update DIV content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have DIV with scroll-y and I update content on this DIV via $.get. I don't know how I can make auto scrolldown when new content (on DIV) is longer than old content.

CSS

```
#chat-conversations{
    background-color: red;
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Here is the **[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/nRg7V/6/)**

Comment: What have you already tried? Please share your existing code.

Comment: anything you have tried? if means, post the lines.

Comment: This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/nRg7V/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your div's scrolltop to your div's scrollHeight.

```
var yourDiv = document.getElementById("chat-conversations");
yourDiv.scrollTop = yourDiv.scrollHeight;
```

Put this inside $.get's Callback function after appending content to div, this will auto scroll div to the new content.

Update: Sorry bruv. i left a typo.corrected now

Comment: @Ravi has a typo on his code (second line), `your` is `yourDiv`.