# What is the difference between Websocket,Server Sent Events (SSE) and HTTP2's Server Pushing?

Tags: http, websocket, push-notification, http2

Can someone brief about the difference between these **looking-similar** techniques?

- Websocket
- Server sent events (SSE)
- HTTP2's Server Pushing

I knew all these 3 are "**pushing**" response from server **instead** of requesting by the client.

**At the first look**, it seems all are **same**.I need to get more clarity about the differences.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Websockets: asynchronous communication in both directions. So far doesn't work well with HTTP/2, but efforts are ongoing to make it so. (For example [WISH](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-yoshino-wish-00) and [websockets2-over-http2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-svirid-websocket2-over-http2-00).)

SSE: server can notify the browser of events. Uses normal HTTP and works well even with HTTP/2.  It's possible to emulate asynchronous communication in both directions with SSE by issuing notifications from client to server via regular POST requests, in HTTP/2 these requests go in the same socket with everything else for the same origin and therefore the cost of establishing a new connection can be avoided. However, there may be processing costs on the server side for processing a POST request which are greater than using native websockets.

HTTP/2 Push: absolutely unrelated to the two above, it is a mechanism for a server to push assets to the browser in advance. Possible application: [sending CSSs and Javascripts while the PHP engine is creating the HTML](https://www.shimmercat.com/en/blog/articles/under-the-green-bar/). In theory, HTTP/2 Push and SSE can be combined to make events available to the browser without the initial round-trip delay.

Comment: This is a cool short version... but it hides pitfalls and inaccuracies in favor of providing a good overview, There's more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28197906/4025095), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195452/websockets-vs-server-sent-events-eventsource) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582935/does-http-2-make-websockets-obsolete)... Also, Websockets works perfectly with HTTP/2 by falling back to HTTP/1.1 during the handshake. Past efforts to merge HTTP/2 with Websockets have been abandoned and though there might be new efforts, I don't know of any.

Comment: @Myst: See edits by Daniel Stenberg to my answer. WISH and websockets2-over-http2 are being discussed at the w3-wg mailing list.