# Real-time notification and result receiving

Tags: rest, api, websocket, polling, long-polling

What the best practices to organize `REST API` with realtime notification of long operations? 
I assume that I can retrieve `operationID` and then receive real-time operation status through `WebSockets`.

But which the best option to get results? 
I guess this is not a good practice to mix notification and retrieving of the result.

Consequently, I need to perform polling or long polling for the results on another endpoint. 
Is that a good practice?

Answer (score 1):

There is some additional options for  long operations:

- `webhooks`(trigger some endpoint when operation was done).
- `push notifications` when done(if long-running operation was triggered from client).
- use `queues` for long-running operations (send message to queue when the operation was done).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on concrete situations. Because your question is general, I also give a general answer: simpler is better.

> I guess this is not a good practice to mix notification and
>   retrieving of the result.

I do not see anything not good here, you can use the same channel with format like this for each response:{"status":"in-progress","workload":"72%"} and {"status":"finish","result":"ok"}

If you do not have any obvious reason to use different channels for notification and result, just use a single channel for all kinds of responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
Consequently, I need to perform polling or long polling for the
results on another endpoint. Is that a good practice?
```

It's not in real production.

Each *long* polling is opening a thread on your server, it's cpu intensive.

Long polling handpoints are easy target for various automated [DDOS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Attack_techniques).

> The underlying effectiveness of most DDoS attacks comes from the
> **disparity between the amount of resources** it takes to launch an attack
> relative to the amount of resources it takes to absorb or mitigate
> one. While this is still the case with L7 attacks, the efficiency of
> affecting both the targeted server and the network requires less total
> bandwidth to achieve the same disruptive effect; an application layer
> attack creates more damage with less total bandwidth.
> https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/application-layer-ddos-attack/

Your server will be easy to pull down with few malicious connections.

Use a proper `wss` websockets architecture, full-duplex communication channels over `tls` encryption, this is the way to go.

It's very efficient regarding data consumption, and power usage overtime. This is to take into account, following my tests, if your clients uses smartphones, the battery really likes websockets over loops of api calls.

Remember, it's still a new born protocol from 2011.

[The WebSocket Protocol RFC6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

But our browsers have now sweats reliable and native `WebSocket` capabilities.

> The (*javascript*) WebSocket API is an advanced technology that makes it possible to
> open a two-way interactive communication session between the user's
> browser and a server. With this API, you can send messages to a server
> and receive event-driven responses **without having to poll the
> server** for a reply.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API

---

Example opening a `wss` websocket and send some [jsonRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC)  datas from native javascript:

```js
let socket = "wss://echo.websocket.org:443";
  let jsonRPC= {
    "method": "my_call",
    "id": 123
  }
Wsock = new WebSocket(socket)
Wsock.onopen = function(event) {
  this.onclose = function(event) {
      console.log("CLOSED SOCKET")
    }
  this.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e)
    }
   this.send(JSON.stringify(jsonRPC), function(response){
        console.log(response)
    });  
  }
```

Debugger network tab capture with the above script, output `101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake`

[image]

Comment: Disagree with you. ASP.NET Core can keep connections without keeping a thread using async controllers.

Answer (score -1):

Based on this

> [Short-polling vs Long-polling for real time web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642598/short-polling-vs-long-polling-for-real-time-web-applications)

: I suggest as Open source long polling solutions:

> Go https://github.com/jcuga/golongpoll
>
> PHP: https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling
>
> Node.js: https://github.com/fanout/pollymer

Best practices !

Comment: Your link is a tutorial from 2011.