# How to wait while the server doesn't respond?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a webpage with some interactions between users and I'm a bit lost.

Any guidance is welcome.

Imagine the following scenario:

- Client A opens a 'public' webpage and pressess a button.
- Client A starts waiting for the response of client B
- Client B goes to an 'admin' webpage and presses a button.
- Client A receives the information that client B had pressed a button.

The overall idea to have a page were client A can click a button "I'm ready to play" and starts waiting for client B's response. Client B receives a notification and presses a button "I'm ready too". Client A receives a notification telling Client B is ready too.

I know this could be done with AJAX. But I'm not really sure how to 'wait' for the client B response and update the webpage when the response arrive.

Any help / tip is welcome.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: [This answer contains three options that would work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642598/short-polling-vs-long-polling-for-real-time-web-applications#28197906): Short-polling, long-polling, and web-sockets.

Comment: WebRTC is another approach

Comment: As Alexander mentioned the technical term you're looking out is Polling. And Websockets may help you with that.

Comment: Polling looks what I need I'm studying it and looking for a sample code. If any of you have a sample code that can share that's welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

## Asynchronous

You seem to think in synchronous way, but that's not how you should think about this. You are issuing a command to the server, but you should not *wait* for the response, because:

- the command might never arrive, for ex. due to Internet connectivity issues
- the server might be down
- the server might error out your command and never respond
- the other player might never receive the message
- the other player might never answer the message
- the server might never receive the other player's command
- the server might error out the other player's command
- the server might never send you the notification
- you might never receive the notification

So many point of possible failure on the one hand. And... Javascript is single-threaded on the other hand. So, if you *wait* for the other player to respond, then your UI will froze in the meantime (with the exception of [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), but that's a more advanced topic, for now, let's view Javascript as a single-threaded environment)

Instead you should think asynchronously. In fact, in the achronim of AJAX, the first "A" stands for "Asynchronous". This means that you issue a request and define what you will do when a response is received. This "what will you do" is called the **callback**. Your client-side will work and be responsive in the meantime and when a response arrives it will know what to do.

## Not only your request, but the other's response

Okay, now that we think asynchronously, we need to consider our options to handle when the other player decides to join your game:

### Polling

You may issue periodic requests to the server via `setTimeout` and AJAX requests and once the response notifies you about the game being accepted, handle it accordingly. See: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-polling

### Push notifications

The server may send notifications to the users once an event occurs. See: https://onesignal.com/lp-web-push?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=general&gclid=CjwKCAjw4_H6BRALEiwAvgfzq9s03BR1OhlvxwN6SCn6Q_bIKODk3bQK05gwdaHTpwvzV2d7mXQU9hoCSl4QAvD_BwE

But you may want to use something that's compatible with what you are using at the server.

### WebSockets

WebSockets are duplex channels, which are kept open. If the framework is implemented and supported, then client A and client B would both be connected, client A would send a command via WebSocket, the server would receive that and notify client B via WebSocket. When client B decides to accept the challenge, he would click on the button, which would issue a command of his own to the server via WebSocket and the server would notify client A via WebSocket. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket

## Summary

It's better to view this as a series of events and event handlers, rather than waiting for a response.