# how to detect XMLHttpRequest and add function

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on php project,

I have 2 pages, data is synchronized between pages using XMLHttpRequest .

When i click button on the first page, the dom in the second page is updated .

I have this function :

```
function getAlertes(popup) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //Action en réponse de la requête
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (popup) {
                document.getElementById("popup-container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("listAlertes").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
            toggleListInvisible();
        }
    };
    // Préparation et envoi de la requête au serveur
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../../private/controller/action_list_alertes.php?popup=" + popup, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

This js script allow to add a div eatch time a button is clicked :

[image]

How can i fetch the data eatch time an XMLHttpRequest is detected in the destination page ?

I tried this :

```
function getAlertes(popup) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //Action en réponse de la requête
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            if (popup) {
                document.getElementById("popup-container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                const audio = new Audio("../audio/BELLDoor_Doorbell.wav");
                audio.play();
            } else {
                document.getElementById("listAlertes").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
            toggleListInvisible();
        }
    };
    // Préparation et envoi de la requête au serveur
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "../../private/controller/action_list_alertes.php?popup=" + popup, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

i need to play sound when the dom is updated by in this cas the sound is played for every XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: First, XmlHttpRequest is not special in any way, it is just a wrapper for JS to use. There is a [common pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2579271/231316) that you can look for a special header, but it is not secure and there's arguably better ways. So instead, you have a page where you click a button and an HTTP GET request is sent to the server. On your second page, you need a method for it to [listen or be told](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28197906/231316) when that happens, and there are many options.

Comment: If all you want to do is to play a sound, then you should do that using JS in your callback, not PHP (which is a _server side_ language and can't play sounds on the _client_).

Comment: I updated my question,  i play sound when this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200, the problem that the sound is alaways played, i only need to play a soud when new div appear

Comment: Don't you know when you make the request if it's going to create a new div or not? In that case, just pass that as an argument to your funciton.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand you

Comment: It seems like this is better suited to inter-window communication ( ie: postMessage, BroadcastChannel etc ) rather than AJAX