# Which are the benefits of Bayeux protocol compared to REST?

Tags: api, performance, rest, microservices, bayeux

I've been using REST but I want more performance when working with large streams of data. Why does Bayeux protocol may be a better idea than REST? Which are the scenarios where Bayeux is the option?

Doing research and working on a POC for now.

Comment: check this first https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_streaming.meta/api_streaming/BayeauxProtocolAndCometD.htm.  then check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642598/short-polling-vs-long-polling-for-real-time-web-applications.  if you want just performance in sync call like rest then better go for RPC communication.

Comment: RPC also can stream in all direction . server stream to client , client stream to server and both together.

Comment: Thanks so much @RouzbehZarandi I will check those resources shared, and will try RPC.